# How to maintain responsive image aspect ratio?

Tags: css

I have an image that has 1900 of width and 1000 of height, and I'm using `background-size: contain;` and `width: 100%;` but I want div height the same of image changed height.

---

Example:

In 1366 screens, the image will reduce the size to fit screen size (width 100%), consequently, the image height will reduce too, so I want to get that height.

---

What I tried to do:

HTML:

```
<header>
    <section class="bg"></section>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header .bg {
    background-image: url('header.jpg');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc((100vw * 1000) / 1900);
    float: left;
}
```

Problem: The vw is calculating with scrollbar width, and I want without, could I use the width % instead of vw?

I accept others ideas to do it, but I prefer using CSS.

Comment: Are you basically trying to create a responsive image, which maintains it's aspect ratio?

Comment: @fubar Exactly...

Comment: Why don't you use img tag?

Comment: If you use img tag, the parent div will have same dimensions as its child img tag. Then have a position absolute child element 
(sibling to img element) which is stretched to the parent element. Now keep your content inside this absolute element.

Comment: @Mr_Green Because I will put content inside the <section class="bg">

Comment: You can still do as I explained above..I am on mobile so not posting the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will maintain it's aspect ratio.

The aspect ratio is calculated by dividing the height by the width:

```
1000 / 1900 = 0.5263
```

It's a little difficult to see this working in a code snippet, so here's a [JSBin link](https://jsbin.com/sapovixuda/1/edit?output) that you can resize too.

```css
.image-wrapper {
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 52.63%; /* 1900:1000 */
}
.image-wrapper .image {
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/1900x1000');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;   
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome resolution, but how can I have the padding-bottom result for other images with other sizes?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: The padding-bottom uses 52.63%, whats the calculation for that?

Comment: It's `height / width`, so `1000px / 1900px = 0.5263...`.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the aspect ratio calculation.